# Java SOAP webservice always return null

Tags: java, soap

I have a simple SOAP webservice server like this:

```
public class receiver extends JAXMServlet implements ReqRespListener {

    public SOAPMessage onMessage(SOAPMessage soapm) {
        return soapm;
    }
}
```

In the client I send a message to this server:

```
public class sender {

    /** This is a sample web service operation */

    SOAPConnectionFactory scfac = null;
    SOAPConnection con =null;
    MessageFactory fac = null;
    SOAPMessage message = null;
    SOAPMessage response = null;
    @WebMethod(operationName = "sender")
    public String sender(@WebParam(name = "a") String a) 
    {
        try{
        //Creat Connection
        scfac = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        con = scfac.createConnection();
        fac = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        message = fac.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
        SOAPHeader header = envelope.getHeader();
        header.detachNode();
        SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
        body.addTextNode(a);
        URL endpoint = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Target/receiver");
        //log("Bat dau gui");
        response = con.call(message, endpoint);
        //log("Da nhan ve");
        SOAPPart sp = response.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope ev = sp.getEnvelope();
        SOAPBody bd = ev.getBody();
        String result = bd.getValue();
        return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String fail = "Fail to send";
            return  fail;
        }
}
}
```

I called the sender function in a jsp file and passed a String to it.
I had built it with Netbeans and Tomcat server but it just responds with a null message.
How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**I had fixed the problem by 2 steps:**

- The SOAP server: In the web.xml file fix the servlet class from *com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet* to your own Java class (in my case it is receive.receiver)
- Add saaj-impl-1.3.1 library to NetBeans (the library with method *com.sun.xml.messaging*)